# Could you help me troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get this code to work and I can't for the life of me understand why it won't. I've tried JSlint and everything.  I've spent less than 2 hours with JavaScript so it my be a daft problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/demo.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       window.onload = init;
function init() {
           document.getElementById("s1").onclick = print(1);
           document.getElementById("s2").onclick = print(2);
           document.getElementById("s3").onclick = print(3);
           document.getElementById("s4").onclick = print(0);
}

       function print(printno) {
       var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
       
       switch(printno)
       {
       case 1:
       demo.innerHTML=  "It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire. ";
        break;
        case 2:
        demo.innerHTML = "During the battle, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire's ultimate weapon, the Death Star, an armored space station with enough power to destroy an entire planet.";
        break;
        case 3:
        demo.innerHTML = "Pursued by the Empire's sinister agents, Princess Leia races home aboard her starship, custodian of the stolen plans that can save her people and restore freedom to the galaxy....";
        break;
        case 0:
        demo.innerHTML = "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away..";
        break;
        }
}

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
        A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away..
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><span id ="s1">Part 1</span></li>
      <li><span id="s2">Part 2</span></li>
      <li><span id="s3">Part 3</span></li>
      <li><span id="s4">Reset</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know! This is why I'm asking.

Comment: @CamMurray What he means to ask is: What do you expect this code to do, and what exactly happens instead?

Answer (score 5):

When you do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("s1").onclick = print(1);
document.getElementById("s2").onclick = print(2);
document.getElementById("s3").onclick = print(3);
document.getElementById("s4").onclick = print(0);
```

you are actually invoking `print()` function with given parameter and then bond result of that function (which is actually `undefined`) to onclick event. I think what you wanted to do was something like this:

```
document.getElementById("s1").onclick = function(){ print(1) };
document.getElementById("s2").onclick = function(){ print(2) };
document.getElementById("s3").onclick = function(){ print(3) };
document.getElementById("s4").onclick = function(){ print(0) };
```

This will attach a function that invokes your `print()` function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zjvnR/

Comment: Thanks Antony! I not certain I comprehend how the fix works but my problem is gone. I shall do some reading. Thanks very much!

Comment: @CamMurray basically, there's a difference between writing `document.getElementById("s1").onclick = print` and `document.getElementById("s1").onclick = print(1)`. In the first case everything is okay, you assign a function to an event handler (but without passing any parameters). In the second case you **first** invoke the function, and **then** assign the result of that invocation to an event handler.